# Is There A Way To Make Flowey Like you?

Tags: undertale

So I just got Undertale, but I've known pretty much everything about it for three or more months. What I don't know is all of the endings for neutral routes. I first started with a couple of pacifist runs, but now I've grown a love for neutral. I first spared everyone but the bosses, which meant I had to kill Flowey. But since he's my favorite character, I didn't. In the end, Flowey asked me if I could prove to him that I could make it through a run without killing anyone to get a better ending. I wasn't done with neutral routes though. So naturally, I reset the game. When I saw Flowey again in his little spot where you first meet him, he said something like "Hey. Remember what I said? Don't kill anyone." Then he popped into the ground and Toriel came.

I did as he said and made it through most of the game without killing anyone. But when it came to Asgore, I decided not to spare him, just to test it out. As a result, Flowey got a bit angry. He said something similar to "You made all of these friends, just to kill ASGORE? What the hell is wrong with you?" and "Are you trolling me? You're only trolling yourself." When I reset the game, Flowey wasn't there at the beginning.

Once again, I decided to do a neutral route. But this time, I kill everyone EXCEPT the bosses. So that's what I did. After I spared Toriel, I was thinking of seeing Flowey again, have him scold at me a bit, and reset. But he didn't appear after that either. And like the previous run, I wasn't able to fight Omega because Flowey knew what would happen. So I hurried through the credits, skipped through Sans's call (which I didn't read because I skipped through so fast, but I know he said something different that time), and got to Flowey. He said "Why do you keep coming here? Oh wait, I get it. You want to be friends, don't you? You're PATHETIC." He then talks about how he could get along with someone like himself.

I reset the game again, but I haven't done anything yet. I made it to Flowey's spot, but once again, he's not there. I wonder if he's pushing me towards a genocide route, which was my original plan until now, or should I continue to go through neutrals just to see was he says. Maybe, he might give up. I'm not sure. But if there's one thing I'm sure about, it's that *I* am not giving up. So back to the question, can you possibly make Flowey like you, without going through a genocide route? I don't think I should go through genocide yet for two reasons. One, because then Flowey's memory will be reset when I give my soul to Chara, and two, because I don't want to see Flowey die.

Answer (score 4):

You've obviously already read some spoilers, but I'm not sure exactly what you do and don't know, so I'll be using spoiler markup anyway.

First, a direct answer to your question with the bare minimum of spoilers possible:

> If you do the True Pacifist route, then Flowey will be sincerely nice to you, and wish that you were his friend. This requires you to go through the entire game without killing *any* monster at all (0 EXP earned, LV 1), and also requires you to befriend several monsters along the way. If you are missing another aspect of the route, Flowey would normally give you a hint about it after the credits (he has already given you the "don't kill anyone" hint, and he's not going to repeat himself). However, killing Asgore causes him to yell at you for that instead, even though it's after the point of no return and therefore not strictly relevant.

Now for the spoiler you probably *don't* want to read unless you already know everything about the game:

> Flowey is really the last remnants of Asriel Dreemurr. He is generally unable to feel positive emotions, and as a result, he will never truly be friends with the protagonist, or with any other character, unless he's returned to his original form. This only happens in the True Pacifist ending, and only temporarily.

Answer (score -1):

How I got Flowey to like me was I did a neutral run where I killed all monsters and spared all bosses but, at the end I killed Flowey. Then I started a genocide route, and after you kill Toriel, Flowey will team up with you meaning you have befriended him and Flowey will say “Let’s grind em’ to dust.” thus you get Flowey to like you because he says you're just like him, “hollow inside” and I transformed it into a new route called “The pure evil route” because you are like Flowey's sidekick and you are evil.

Comment: This is way different from the accepted answer. Is there a source?

Answer (score -4):

If you do a 'true pacifist' run (meaning don't kill anyone), then you must have a date with papyrus and go to the true lab. When you go to Asgore, everyone shows up, and Papyrus says that a little flower told you to come here. Asriel and Dreemur fight, and then he hugs you after sparing him and says take good care of Mom and Dad (Toriel and Asgore) and that technically means his your friend. I don't know any other way